# Camera freezes if didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is defined

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I'm trying to do a basic picture taking with iPhone. I used the following code to show the camera:

```
 - (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                       usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                       UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

        if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
              UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
            || (delegate == nil)
            || (controller == nil))
            return NO;


        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
        // movie capture, if both are available:
        cameraUI.mediaTypes =
        [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

        // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
        // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

        cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

This works fine, but then if I define the handling function:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

}
```

The imagePicker control freezes after pressing the Use button. It doesn't crash, doesn't throw any exception, the code is doing something, but on the screen I just see the frozen imagePicker control. Even if the handler is empty the control freezes. If I remove the handler, the camera disappears normally and shows the view from where the camera was activated...
Did I miss something essential here?

*UPDATE:*
I tried assigning the image to an UIImageView, the code executes, exits the function and that's it, the camera remains on the screen:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage* original =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [[self imgWLItemImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:original.CGImage scale:0.25 orientation:original.imageOrientation]];
}
```

Comment: Where you want to save capture image? write code for saving images where you want in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method...

Comment: I just want to show the image in the UIImage control, but the thing is - whatever I do in this function, it doesn't matter. If it is defined, the camera freezes. If I step through the code, it executes all the statements in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, exits it, and that's it. Nothing else happens. ImagePicker doesn't disappear from the screen, and the code is doing something, no crash.

Comment: You should show capture image in imageview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this & check:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage* original =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [[self imgWLItemImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:original.CGImage scale:0.25 orientation:original.imageOrientation]];
}
```

Comment: Was exactly what I was searching for. in Xcode 4.6 you have to use: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`